# Refresh a dynamic created fieldset

Tags: jquery-mobile, dynamic, checkbox, refresh, fieldset

how can i refresh a dynamic created fieldset with checkbox? 
I fill the checkbox with local loaded data. If i click a delete button and the local saved data is deleted so the fieldset with the checkbox should be refreshed.
I tried

```
$('#fieldset_item').trigger("create");
$('#item_List').trigger("create");
```

fieldset_item is the name of fieldset and item_List the name of the page.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587333/jquery-mobile-create-dynamic-controlgroup-and-apply-jquery-ui-css

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#fieldset_item').trigger("create");
$('#item_List').trigger("create");
$('#fieldset_item').page();
$('#item_List').page();
```

This works great for me.